# How can I find the limit of a sequence containing $\sin n!$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}
\frac{n^{2/3} \sin n!}{n+1}
\end{equation*}$$

I know that I should divide numerator and denominator by the highest power of n in the denominator but then what? how can I deal with the $n!$ which is the angle of the sine? I know that $n!$ is larger than $n$ and I know also that $|\sin n| \leq 1$, but how can I organize all this information to use it in my solution?

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: No matter what the value of $n!$ is, can you maybe give a (simple) upper bound on $\lvert \sin(n!)\rvert$?

Comment: I think it is 1....correct? @ClementC.

Comment: Yes. (This is exactly what the two answers do, incidentally.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to worry about the factorial at all, since $|\sin(n!)|\le1$ just like $|\sin n|$.  So

$$\left|n^{2/3}\sin(n!)\over n+1 \right|\le\left|n^{2/3}\over n+1 \right|\le\left| n^{2/3}\over n\right|={1\over n^{1/3}}\to0$$

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$0\leq |\frac{n^{2/3}\sin n!}{n+1}|=\frac{n^{2/3}|\sin n!|}{n+1}\leq\frac{n^{2/3}}{n+1}\leq\frac{n^{2/3}}{n}=n^{-1/3}\to 0(n\to\infty)$$

To elaborate, the first two steps are just rules for absolute values and products. Note that $|\sin n!|$ ranges between $0$ and $1$, as $\sin n!$ ranges between $-1$ and $1$, i.e. as an upper bound $|\sin n!|\leq 1$. The factorial has no impact as the sine, ranging from $-1$ to $1$, is periodically over all of $\mathbb{R}$. Lastly, we just decrease the denominator to finally cross out the $n$ term.

By the [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), it follows that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{n^{2/3}\sin n!}{n+1}|=0$$ and as $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ iff $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|=0$ for any real sequence $(a_n)_n$, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{2/3}\sin n!}{n+1}=0$$